# JQuery Dialog not opening on single click

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am opening a jquery dialog on button click.I am opening panel as dialog.
In that panel there is iframe and in that iframe src I have called the new page.
Popup is opening properly at the first time.
I am closing the popup and by clicking on button to open the popup again.
When I am opening the popup 2nd time I am facing 2 problems

1. If I click on the button 1st time popup is not opening. If I again click the button 2nd time then popup opens. Popup is opening on 2nd click but not on 1st click. I am not able to find out why the popup is not opening on single click and opening on double click.
2. I have TextBox control in popup. When I open popup 2nd time in IE this TextBox control is in disabled state. If I fire any server side event in that page like button click then that TextBox control gets enabled. While in Mozilla Firefox it is working properly. That TextBox control is always in enabled state.

Please let me know how can I solve this problems.

My jquery function is as follows

```
function OpenPopupTest()
{
    $("#PanelTest").dialog(
    {                    
        minWidth: 500,
        minHeight: 500
    });
}
```

I am calling the following panel

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelTest" runat="server" Style="display: none; background-color: White;
    font-size: 12px;">
    <div id="DivTst" style="text-align: left; margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 10px">
        <iframe id="iframeTest" src="Test1.aspx" height="400px" width="400px"></iframe>
        <br />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>

<button ID="ButtonTest" runat="server" Value="Open Popup" />
```

This button is inside update panel.

In code behind on botton attribute I am calling the javascript function.
    ButtonTest.Attributes.Add("onclick","OpenPopupTest()");

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Rahul Rathi

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to dialog is incorrect. For a reusable dialog you want to initialize it when page loads, then use your button only to open it

```
/* initialize dialog on page load*/
$(function(){
    $("#PanelTest").dialog(
    {                    
        minWidth: 500,
        minHeight: 500,
        autoOpen: false
    });    
});

function OpenPopupTest()
{
    $("#PanelTest").dialog('open')
}
```